# Running hook_cron with administrator privileges in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there a way to allow `hook_cron` to run with administrator privileges -- e.g a sort of `sudo hook_cron()` as it were?

This question is a follow up to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235326/drupals-profilesaveprofile-doesnt-work-in-hookcron-when-run-by-the-servers) trying to diagnose why hook_cron() functions invoked by `/drupal/cron.php` run differently that the same functions invoked by `/admin/reports/status/run-cron`.

My particular function (call it `foo_cron()`) updates user profiles as part of its nightly duties. But, `/drupal/cron.php` apparently runs as an anonymous user. Anonymous users cannot modify user profile fields in this site, for obvious reasons, so this part of the script fails.

I know I can work around this by modifying `profile_fields` directly using SQL, but that feels like an ugly hack, and could be tough to maintain if I start doing this in multiple modules.

Is the a way, within the existing Drupal functions and framework, to make certain foo_cron() jobs run with privs that we normally only give administrators, such as updating profiles?

This particular site is running Drupal 6.1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [drupal cron manual page](http://drupal.org/cron): 
Running cron as an authenticated user

```
#!/bin/sh
# Reference http://drupal.org/node/479948#comment-1673488 by pearlbear

SITE=https://dev.example.com/
USERNAME=user.name
PASS=ChangeMe!!12

COOKIES=/tmp/cron-cookies.txt
WGETPARAMS="--quiet -O /dev/null --no-check-certificate --save-cookies $COOKIES --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies $COOKIES"
# if you run drupal in a default language different than English you need to modify this
LOGIN="Log%20in"

wget $WGETPARAMS "${SITE}user"
wget $WGETPARAMS --post-data="name=$USERNAME&pass=$PASS&op=$LOGIN&form_id=user_login" "${SITE}user"
wget $WGETPARAMS " ${SITE}cron.php"
```

Comment: There is a slight problem with this solution, on the last line you have an extra space inside the hyphens. Please change it as it is hard to debug in a cpanel environment.

Comment: To use this with cPanel, you may also need to add "/bin/sh " before the shell script path.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is save the global $user variable, then change the $user global to a user with that permission and then change the user back again.

Now I wouldn't recommend this but would suggest that you use SQL instead as this approach is very hacky and possible a bit insecure to run cron jobs with admin privs.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why using global $user is hackier than using SQL? My own thought on the matter is that SQL is hackier because it goes outside Drupal to complete a Drupal task, but I'm curious what led you to that.

Comment: It's the core of Drupal core that sets the value of the global variables (during the bootstrap I believe). So altering the value of one temporarily (which effect all of Drupal) is more hacky than writing a bit of SQL yourself thatthe function would generate anyways.